How to wait for function call in Javascript without calling it directly
I have several functions that call each other asyncronously, and I need to catch a situation when last functionis called.
Use Promise in every call does not work for it makes a caller stop and wait, but it should continue.
function First(){
  console.log('First is called');
  setTimeout(Second, 1000);
  console.log('First fired Second and does not wait for its execution');
  return;
}

function Second(){
  console.log('Second is called');
  setTimeout(Last, 1000);
}
function Last(){
  console.log('Last is called');
}
function Main(){
  First();
  // somehow wait for Last to be executed
  console.log('called First and continue only after Last is done');
}

I expect to see in the log:

First is called
First fired Second and does not wait for its execution
// now one second delay
Second is called
...
Last is called
called First and continue only after Last is done


Would you be calling Second() twice, if you're waiting until Second() is called before calling First()? Adding async/await keywords shouldn't be terribly complicated.

setTimeout(Second(), 1000); should be setTimeout(Second, 1000);. Otherwise you call the function immediately, not after the timeout.

I'm assuming there's more to these that actually require them to be asynchronous, but I really think you can just throw an async in front of each function definition, then await when you call each async function.

@mykaf setTimeout() doesn't return a promise, you can't await it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep?noredirect=1&lq=1 for how you can write a sleep() function that you can await.

"The solution could be an infinite loop in Main until Second initiate a variable," No, that won't work. The infinite loop will prevent the timeout function from ever running.

The "infinite loop" could be a setInterval operation which keeps polling for some observable side-effect.  But the "more clear solution" alluded to at the end of the question would really be to make use of Promises.  Once that setTimeout is wrapped in a Promise then everything up the chain can become async and can be awaited where appropriate.

Alternatively, perhaps you're looking to emit a custom event and handle that event somewhere?  The example shown may not fully represent the problem.

Just make an async wait() utility function:


const wait = (timeout = 0) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, timeout));

async function First(){
  console.log('First is called');
  await wait(1000);
  Second();
}

function Second(){
  console.log('Second is called');
}

async function Main(){
  await First();
  console.log('I called First and I want that Second also is complete');
}

Main();




you can use Promises. In your case, you can modify your First and Second functions to return Promises. This way, you can await the completion of Second without having to call it directly.
like this
function First() {
  console.log('First is called');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Second();
      resolve(); // Resolve the promise after Second is called
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function Second() {
  console.log('Second is called');
}

async function Main() {
  await First(); // Wait for First to complete
  console.log('I called First and I want that Second also is complete');
}

Main();

If you have a long chain of asynchronous functions where each function calls the next, you can still use Promises effectively.
function First() {
  console.log('First is called');

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Second().then(resolve); // Call Second and wait for it to resolve
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function Second() {
  console.log('Second is called');

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Third().then(resolve); // Call Third and wait for it to resolve
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function Third() {
  console.log('Third is called');

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      LastFunction().then(resolve); // Call LastFunction and wait for it to resolve
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function LastFunction() {
  console.log('Last function is called');

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(); // Resolve when the last function is done
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function Main() {
  await First(); // Wait for the entire chain to complete
  console.log('All functions are complete');
}

// Call Main to start the process
Main();

if this is what do you mean by catching the last one

Thanks for an idea,but the problem is that a chain is very long. First call seconfd, second calls Third and so on and it is necessary to catch the last.

@DmitryKlavdiev: If every call along that chain is performing an asynchronous operation then every call along that chain should similarly return a Promise.  Perhaps the example given in the question doesn't entirely demonstrate the problem?

@DmitryKlavdiev

Calling every function with Promise makes every function to wait until a call is done. In suggested by @zakaria the function First is still working when Second is being executed. It should set a timeout and return.
Look, this will work:
var StillWorking = false;
function First(){
  console.log('First');
  StillWorking = true;
  setTimeout(Second, 1000);
  return;
}
function Second(){
  console.log('Second');
  StillWorking = false;
}
function Main(){
    First();
    while (StillWorking);
    console.log('All done');
}

But the infinite loop seems to be too dumb

@DmitryKlavdiev if you want the functions to run asynchronously and don't want each function to wait for the previous one to complete, you can indeed use setTimeout without chaining Promises so in each function you will use setTimeout like setTimeout(Second, 1000).

@DmitryKlavdiev it doesn't matter how long your chain is... the solution is the same. If you want the calling method to know when the called method is done... the called method needs to indicate that in one way or another. Promises and/or async/await are the tools you use to accomplish that.

@DmitryKlavdiev: Perhaps you could clarify in the question why you don't want to use Promises at all?  It still sounds like the example shown simply doesn't demonstrate the problem.  (Or at least doesn't demonstrate what you might think the problem is.)

This does not properly handle exceptions from Second. Do pass resolve directly to setTimeout, and call other functions in .then() callbacks afterwards.

@David, Promise simply make a code stop for waiting the result. You could use Delay(1000); Second(); instead of Promise and setTimeout if there were a Delay function. I only whish to wait for a callback, but not the functions that reach to call it. So I agree to use a kind of Promise in Main(), but not in First(). Alas then, it seems there is no direct solution. And sorry for not clear task description. @zakaria thank you, it's clear but it is not what I need.

@DmitryKlavdiev: "if there were a Delay function" - There is.  "I only whish to wait for a callback, but not the functions that reach to call it." - You don't have to await at every level.  The example provided has only one asynchronous operation to be awaited.  So the answers regarding that example are indeed awaiting at every level, all one of them.  Perhaps you could update the question to include an example of the actual problem you're trying to solve, and not a contrived approximation that's easily solved with Promises?

Colleagues,this is how it works as necessary:


const delay = (timeout = 0) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, timeout));
var StillWorking = false;
function First(){
  console.log('First started');
  StillWorking = true;
  setTimeout(Second, 1000);
  console.log('First fired Second and continue working');
  return;
}
function Second(){
  console.log('Second');
  StillWorking = false;
}
async function Main(){
    console.log('Main');
    First();
    while (StillWorking) await delay(10);
    console.log('All done');
}
Main();



First function should not wait until Second is finished. The only task is to make Main to wait for calling a function Second, so I cannot use Promise when calling Second.
But all the code seems very dumb, with a global variable and infinite loop. Yet I do not see more accurate solution.
